# Share same variable among multiple js scripts - one has .ready function and other doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, share

I have 2 js script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function capture(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var video = document.getElementById('video');
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
alert(img);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() { 

 $(".post").click(function() { alert(img);
 var level = document.getElementById('level');
 var language = document.getElementById('language');
 var textac = document.getElementById('textac');
 var decribac = document.getElementById('decribac');
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
url: "love.php",

data: {img: img, language: language, level: level, decribac:decribac, textac: textac },
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){

   }});
     window.location.replace("love.php");

   });
   });
   </script>
```

What they do is first one on click on 'capture' makes a thumbnail of video and puts it in canvas and saves the var img. And other one on click of another button 'post' posts everything via ajax including the image base64 encoded string. My problem is that when I try to click 'post' console loggs out

```
-  404 Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined
```

And I dont know why as if I alert it in the first script it gets alerted correctelly but second one doesnt know it. And if i put the capture finction under

```
   $(document).ready(function(){..});
```

then it doenst work and console says - capture function is undefined. Thats also weird. And if I dont put the second button handler it doesnt do anything on click. So I needed to put them in their own scripts - one with .ready function and one without. Now I cant get the img var to the second script to send it via ajax to the php script. Help.

Comment: What is `img` ? It has to be `global` or `passed as argument` to be accesses by other `methods/functions`...

Comment: I need to access it in clecked button '.post' even handler to pass it via AJAX

Answer (score 1):

You define that variable inside a function:

```
function capture(){
    //...
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    //...
}
```

So it exists only within the scope of that function.  If it needs to be global, define it globally:

```
var img;

function capture(){
    //...
    img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    //...
}
```

That would attach it to the `window` object where it can be accessed by by other code within the overall window scope.

Comment: Invoking `capture` and returning `datatURL` will be better approach as it would not need `global-variable`

Comment: @Rayon: I'm inclined to agree, but nowhere in the posted code is `capture()` even being invoked.  So we don't really know the overall structure.  Avoiding global scope may involve some re-design in this case.

Comment: I've set the variable at the very top before capture function - and the alert in ajax call says its undefinde. I wonder what am i doing wrong and - the idea of returning var img from capture function seems good - but i dont know how then to 'ask' for it when i'll need it. in other words - how to return it exactelly to ajax call?

Comment: @DonaldaDonalda: Can you update the question with the current code that still demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I guess you never invoke `capture` and that is the reason `img` remains `undefined`..